# Como convertir un JObject a List<>

Tags: c#, json, .net

Al hacer una petición a un servicio rest obtengo un JSon como el siguiente:

```
{
"-LWOV1O6vcehVv4AhTQr": {
    "password": "123456",
    "user": "juana",
    "website": "www.juana.com"
},
"-LWOV2VTAhMRhRygK0nZ": {
    "password": "123456",
    "user": "Andrea",
    "website": "www.andrea.com"
}
```

}

Lo que necesito es convertir este JSon a una `List<LoginData>` usando Newtonsoft.Json donde LoginData es una clase con la siguiente estructura:

```
public class LoginDataResponse
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }


    public string User { get; set; }


    public string Website { get; set; }
}
```

La solución que estaba implementando era convertir el JSON a un JObject y mediante un foreach recorrerlo agregando cada elemento a una lista.

//almaceno en resp el Jobject despues de hacer la conversion

```
var resp = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)response.Result;

List<LoginData> dataList = new List<LoginData>();



            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> jToken in resp)
            {

                ListLoginData.Add(new LoginData
                {
                    Id=  jToken.Key,
                    User = jToken.Value["user"].ToString(),
                    Password = jToken.Value["password"].ToString(),
                    Website = jToken.Value["website"].ToString()

                });

            }
```

El problema es que la petición Get va a retornar un JSon con miles de elementos no como en este que solo retorno dos, entonces no se si seria la manera optima de hacer esto, como puedo hacer una conversión directamente.

Comment: quien definio en el servicio retornar una estructura json con un diseño tan horrible?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy utilizando la base de datos de Firebase y no sé cómo almacenar eso datos en una Array

Comment: pero firebase puede consultarse directamente, no necesitas obtener todos y luego filtrar en memoria https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

Podrias ayudarte con linq, algo como ser

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
                        '-LWOV1O6vcehVv4AhTQr': {
                            'password': '123456',
                            'user': 'juana',
                            'website': 'www.juana.com'
                        },
                        '-LWOV2VTAhMRhRygK0nZ': {
                            'password': '123456',
                            'user': 'Andrea',
                            'website': 'www.andrea.com'
                        }
                        }";

        JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

        var result = from item in jObj.Properties()
                     select new LoginDataResponse(){
                         Password = item.Value["password"].ToString(),
                         User = item.Value["user"].ToString(),
                         Website = item.Value["website"].ToString()
                     };

        foreach(var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", item.User, item.Password, item.Website);
        }

    }
}


public class LoginDataResponse
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
}
```

basicamente iteras las propiedades, para obtener sus valores

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que usaré esta forma.