# Deserializar un JSON con nombres de propiedad variable

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
{
  "-LY2_Np3-jTOC9T0-Xzb": {
      "Descripcion": "Se realizo una factura(p) en tienda: 3 por el usuario: ARMANDO",
      "Fecha": "2019-02-06",
      "Hora": "10:13:01 AM",
      "Monto": "10763.5",
      "Tipo": "Transaccion"
  },
  "-LY2j1Fbl195pooEich8": {
      "Descripcion": "Se realizo una factura(f) en tienda: 3 por el usuario: ARMANDO",
      "Fecha": "2019-02-06",
      "Hora": "10:55:10 AM",
      "Monto": "26900",
      "Tipo": "Transaccion"
  },
  "-LY2jyHCM1DtZAxdxt7W": {
      "Descripcion": "Se realizo una factura(p) en tienda: 3 por el usuario: ARMANDO",
      "Fecha": "2019-02-06",
      "Hora": "10:59:16 AM",
      "Monto": "29830",
      "Tipo": "Transaccion"
  },
  "-LY2nQxcbMGO0oP5vmOM": {
      "Descripcion": "Se realizo una factura(p) en tienda: 3 por el usuario: ARMANDO",
      "Fecha": "2019-02-06",
      "Hora": "11:14:24 AM",
      "Monto": "9830",
      "Tipo": "Transaccion"
  }
}
```

Como se puede observar el id es dinámico. ¿Cómo puedo deserializar este archivo en C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui

[Como convertir un JObject a List<>](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233048/como-convertir-un-jobject-a-list)

se planteo el mismo problema, en donde tiene propiedades dinamicas.

Basicamente defines la clase

```
public class Class1
{
   public string Descripcion { get; set; }
   public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
   //resto propiedades
}
```

Y luego puedes usar `JObject.Parse()`

```
   JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    var result = from item in jObj.Properties()
                 select new Class1(){
                     Descripcion = item.Value["Descripcion"].ToString(),
                     Fecha= Convert.ToDateTime(item.Value["Fecha"]),
                     //resto
                 };

    foreach(var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, ...", item.Descripcion , item.Fecha, ...);
    }
```

Comment: Pura  vida Leandro. Gracias,me funciono.

Comment: Leandro como se haria esto al reves?? Es decir en lugar de deserealizar, Serealizarlo??

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez la verdad es que no sabria decirte porque nunca diseñaria un json de esta forma, es una pesima idea tener propiedades como las de este caso cuando esta claro que deberia usarse un array o lista

Answer (score 3):

En estos casos puedes deserializar utilizando un `Dictionary`.  Creas una clase para los items

```
public class Item
{
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Hora { get; set; }
    public string Monto { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Y luego deserializas así:

```
var resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);
```

Cada uno de los keys del diccionario son los ids, por ejemplo puedes obtener el primer elemento así:

```
var item = resultado["-LY2_Np3-jTOC9T0-Xzb"];
```